# How to set visibility for include layout in databinding?

Tags: java, android, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I have implemented data binding in my project. I have a particular screen with two nested layouts in include tags. I couldn't change the visibility for include layouts using data binding programmatically.

However, I have achieved it through a boolean, but my question is how to set visibility for that include tag programmatically.

My xml:

```xml
<include
  android:id="@+id/reg_email"
  layout="@layout/custom_email"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


<include
  android:id="@+id/reg_phone"
  layout="@layout/custom_phone"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And in Activity:
when I try to set this - it becomes red meaning it doesn't take it as a view.

```java
  dataBinding.regPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  dataBinding.regEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Does the root of your xml is `<layout>` ?

Comment: yes it is. I have data binding in my xml

Comment: And the line dataBinding.regPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE) alone doesn’t work ? Other binding on your layout are working ?

Comment: yes, all the other bindings are working fine. When I try with include it doesn't, since it doesn't consider it as a View rather as an Id  for the nested layout inside it.

Comment: To bind included layouts you just add an id attribute to your included layout in your XML. setVisibility() works on every View .. so something is wrong with the included layout which is custom_phone. Can you post the xml code of it ?

Comment: mahdi 's answer worked for me, thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

add get root to your view

```java
dataBinding.regPhone.getRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
dataBinding.regEmail.getRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Why this works? Why without getRoot() it does not work?

Comment: root is the view, without which you can't call setVisibility()

Answer (score 2):

A better way.

On the top layout, declare the boolean or an observable field whose value toggle the visibility of the included layout. Then remember to give the included layout an `id` else it wont work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="show"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:background="@color/colorPrimary">


        <include layout="@layout/progress"
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:visibility="@{show?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the group with reference view id's work for me because I am including the layout using `<merge>` tag.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="emptyStateView,emptyStateDescription"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.searchResultState.result.size() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
```